# Can this be considered an Einstein model of a solid?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

My abstract definition refers to energy tanks (instead of oscillators) and positive integer energy units. My defining conditions are as follows:

1. The energy tanks are distinguishable.
2. The energy tanks do not interact with each other.
3. All the tank energy levels are equiprobable.
4. Each tank can contain from zero to all the energy units.
5. Τhe tanks have positive integer energy levels (i.e. equally spaced).

My question is if the five conditions, that I have set above, plus possibly some more, can make an Einstein model of a solid.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: By refering to things as "energy tanks" you are not really generalising anything, you are just using terminolagy your own terminology that nobody else will understand. Either you need to explain what you mean more fully or use a more standard terms like, say, "an oscillator". I would promote the fact that the tanks have positive integer energy levels (i.e. equally spaced) to a listed assumption. It is one of the key features of the model. I would mention that you are presumably interested in the limit where the number of tanks is large. Other than that looks more or less like an Einstien solid

Comment: Thank you very much @BySymmetry. I have just edited my question accordingly.

Comment: In context one might understand. But without not at all. Distinguishable not interacting tanks could be gas or whatever, if it comes out of not a defined situation.

Comment: All I need is a statistical model, which will reproduce the equations that an Einstein model of a solid will. Multiplicity and entropy for example. I would like my model to be based on the least number of assumptions possible. Is it or not the assumptions/conditions that an Einsten model of a solid, is based on?

Comment: It seems so if by tanks you intend oscillator and they are already supposed to be in a lattice

Comment: @Alchimista. First of all I would like to thank you for your contribution so far! According to you, what is an oscillator if not an energy tank satisfying the conditions that I have set in my first/primary question? What additional conditions/definitions should a lattice impose?

Comment: No I say you just changed s word, tank instead of oscillator.  It seems so to me. Wait fort a specialist.